# Is the sentence correct? "My trouser is tight at the waist."

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

"My trouser is tight at the waist." - Is the sentence correct? Can the word 'trouser' be used instead of 'trousers'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked the word up? [Trousers](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trousers) is a plural noun, like scissors and pliers, and always takes a plural verb.

> My trousers **are** tight at the waist.

Comment: The technical term for these things that are only ever used in the plural, BTW, is [plurale tantum](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Plurale_tantum).